# Getting my code into a new Git repo on VSTS

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops, visual-studio-2017

This is the first time I'll be using Git on VSTS so I need a bit of help with the next steps.

I already have a new solution -- with multiple projects in it -- on my computer. I also created a new project on VSTS.

Here's what I want to do next:

1. I first want to create two branches called "master" and "dev" so that I can manage my continuous integration properly.
2. I then want to "push" my code into the "dev" branch. Not sure what the right terminology is in Git e.g. push, import, clone etc.

After creating the project on VSTS, here's what I'm seeing on the screen. How do I handle the steps I mentioned above from here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Push Existing Repo from commandline, the steps are explained there quite clearly when you click the link on the screen you posted. You can't create the structure remotely, you push a local branch to a specific branch name on the remote. The easiest would be to take your current solution, commit it to a local repo, add the VSTS remote uri to your local repo and then use `git push -u origin master` to push the master branch. Then, checkout a local develop branch (`git checkout -b develop` and push the same branch as your remote using: `git push -u origin develop` to create the structure you want.

Or from the Visual Studio UI, go to the settings tab and add the VSTS remote: rightclick your local master branch and choose "Publish". Then create a new branch from master (from the context menu) and publish that too.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me the check the code in. However, when I try to "connect" to this repo in Visual Studio, it's telling me to clone it. If I point the local folder to where my code is, it tells me "the location already exists and is not empty.  Choose a new folder or an empty folder for the cloned repository. I don't understand why I need to clone it again. All I want to do at this point is to "connect" my local repo to the remote repo so that I can easily check in my code from Visual Studio.

Comment: If the 'origin' remote us the vsts repo and you are connected to the vsts project it should 'auto detect' and link up. In the last 2017 builds this has been a bit flakey for some reason. Cloning once will solve the issue. Not sure what causes it.

Comment: After closing Visual Studio and reopening it, it now seems to be connected and not asking me to clone. I'd hate to be a bother but I do have two more questions if I may. First, which branch am I connected to through Visual Studio? It doesn't show me anything about the branch. Second question: when I opened "Repository Settings", it now shows me two entries under "Remotes". They are "MyProjectName" and "Origin". They both have the same exact URI i.e. https://myvstsaccount.visualstudio.com/_git/myproject. Do I need both of them?

Comment: I was able to set the "Develop" as my "default branch" through the VSTS portal. Not sure if that means when I check my code in, it will automatically be pushed into the "Develop" branch because it's the default branch.

Comment: The default branch is used as suggestion when merging or creating a pull request. It's also the default branch to convert to. For your local repository this is handled by the so called upstream. By default when creating a branch from a remote branch, the upstream is set to the upstream branch you're branching from. En, when creating a branch from origin/develop, the upstream is automatically set.

Comment: A local repository can have multiple remote repositories set. Each remote repository gets its own name. There are a few names that are used more commonly. 'origin' is one of them. It signifies the 'source' repository and tends to be where you want to end up eventually when merging. But since you could push to any repository from yours you could also have a GitHub, a repo per major release, a repo for receiving public patches etc. You should be able to safely remove your 'MyProject' remote.

Comment: Thanks again for your responses. I think the primary difficulty I'm having is that I'm coming into Git with TFS mindset where things are centralized. I guess one of the primary purposes of Git was to facilitate open source software development where there may be multiple "primary repositories".